# cube.js docker image for aarch64/arm64

Tags: docker, arm64, cube.js

I am new to cube.js and trying to see if I can use it for a small personal project (mostly for learning).

I'm looking for a docker image that runs on Rasberrypi 64 bit - can anyone point me in the right direction please - or maybe it doesn't exist. It would be beyond my skill to work out how to build it for myself.

Comment: Hello @user12891 welcome to stackoverflow and cube.js community, there is a way to install cube.js through Node.js without Docker. here is a link https://cube.dev/docs/getting-started/nodejs

Comment: Thanks. I was really hoping to use Docker, for reasons :)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to use `cubejs/cube:latest` image without qemu.
For [Cube Store](https://cube.dev/docs/deployment/overview#cube-store) you can use `cubejs/cubestore:arm64-experimental-v2021-07-29` image.